Prove total edge length of section is constant? A cross-polytope cut by a hyperplane parallel to a face.
The vertices of a cross-polytope can be chosen as the unit vectors pointing along each co-ordinate axis – i.e. all the permutations of $(±1, 0, 0,\dots, 0)$. The cross-polytope is the convex hull of its vertices.

Consider the section of a cross-polytope $β_n$ with vertices $(±1, 0, 0,\dots, 0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ by the hyperplane $(1,1,\dots,1)\cdot\mathbf x=d$.
Its total edge length is constant for all $|d|<1$.

I verified it for $n=2,3,4$.
I wonder if this is still true for higher dimensions.
For $n=2$, cross-polytope $β_2$ is a square of side length $\sqrt2$. The line $(1,1)\cdot\mathbf{x}=d$ cuts $β_2$ along a segment of constant length $\sqrt2$ for all $|d|<1$.
For $n=3$, cross-polytope $β_3$ is a regular octahedron of edge length $\sqrt2$.
The plane $(1,1,1)\cdot\mathbf{x}=d$ cuts $β_3$ along a hexagon the length of whose perimeter is constant $3\sqrt2$ for all $|d|<1$.

For $n=4$, cross-polytope $β_4$ is a 16-cell of edge length $\sqrt2$.
The hyperplane $(1,1,1,1)\cdot\mathbf x=d$ cuts $β_4$ along a solid with 8 triangle faces and 6 rectangle faces.
Its total edge length is constant $12\sqrt2$ for all $|d|<1$.


Nice question. I'm sure it's true. If true then the total edge length is the total edge length of the simplex with side $\sqrt{2}$ (the zeroth slice), which is $n(n-1)\sqrt{2}/2$ so check your calculation for $n=4$.

I think that at $d=1$ you always have the simplex with the standard basis vectors as vertices. All the "other edges" you see when $d < 1$ have shrunk to $0$.

When $n=4$ The $d=1$ slice is the convex hull of $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)$ . That's a regular tetrahedron.

I think that when $n=4$, the total edge length at $|d|<1$ is twice the total edge length at $d=1$. From the GIF, two edges seem to coincide into one edge when $|d|$ goes to 1.

You're right, and so is @Dr.RichardKlitzing ;s answer.

Let x3o3o..o3o4o ($n$ nodes) be the $n$-D Coxeter-Dynkin diagram of the according regular cross-polytope or orthoplex. Then clearly x3o3o...o3o . ($n-1$ nodes) is the $(n-1)$-D Coxeter-Dynkin diagram of its (all equivalent) facets, then each being according regular simplices.
Note further that the opposite facet here generally happens to be a dually arranged simplex. As a Coxeter-Dynkin diagram this is just o3o3o...o3x (again $n-1$ nodes).
Further those two opposite facets (as bases) are connected by further simplexes (as sides), thus generalising the structure of an antiprism.
Esp. the facet parallel cross-section of the orthoplex then is given by y3o3o...o3z (still $n-1$ nodes), where those two edge sizes are related to the former by $z=x-y$.
And these extremally expanded simplexes x3o3o...o3x ($n-1$ nodes) generally do have $n!/(n-3)!$ edges, i.e. the here half-symmetric variant y3o3o...o3z would have $\frac12 n!/(n-3)!$ edges of size $y$ plus $\frac12 n!/(n-3)!$ edges of size $z=x-y$. This in turn makes clear that the total sum of edge length (in units of length $x$) is just $\frac12 n!/(n-3)!$, independent of sectioning depth (as long as neither $y$ nor $z$ are degenerate).
In contrast, the edge count of the regular $(n-1)$-D simplex x3o3o...o3o, i.e. the facet of the orthoplex, clearly is $\frac12 n!/(n-2)!$.
--- rk

Your final formula is just $n(n-1)/2$, which counts the edges of the simplex. I wonder if there's a more elementary argument than this one using CD diagrams.

$\frac12 n!/(n-3)! = \frac12 n(n-1)(n-2)$ - provided $n>3$, but remind that $0!=1$

Right. See my comments on the original question.
